# Did Shukadevji ( Ved Vyas's son) remain lifelong unmarried?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, marriage

Was Shukadevji ( Ved Vyas' son) lifelong bachelor ?

In [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuka) it is shown that he had wife and children . But in this [quora](https://www.quora.com/Who-were-the-unmarried-men-in-hindu-Puranas-epics/answer/Tushit-Patel-1) answer it is written that he remained lifelong unmarried.

What is the truth ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially, Suka decided not to marry. However, Vyasa, his father, told him to meet king Janaka. After having a discourse with him he changed his mind. He realized that marriage won't be a hindrance in the path of self-realization. Later he got married and had four sons and one daughter. - *Srimad Devi Bhagavatam (also known as Devi Puran or Devi Bhagavat Puran) Book I Chapter 15-19.*

> "...Though Suka adopted the path of Yoga, yet
> he married the daughter of a Muni, named Pivari, very beautiful, fortunate, enhancing the glory of her father's family. Then were born ﬁrst the four sons named Krishna, Gauraprabha, Bhuri, and Devasruta out of the sperm of Suka and the ovum of Pivari; and next a daughter was born named Kirti of them..." - *Srimad Devi Bhagavatam I.19.36-45*

Source -

1. The Srimad Devi Bhagavatam Book I translated by Swami Vijnanananda (Tha Sacred Book of the Hindus Vol. 27 Part I edited by Major B. D. Basu)