# How did Ved-Vyas convince his son Suka to get married?

Tags: marriage, moksha, vyasa, pitru, shuka

[Ved Vyas's son Suka had initially](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50236/23709) decided to remain unmarried, but he was eventually persuaded by Ved-Vyas to get married. Some say that he was told to meet Janaka and after meeting Janaka he got married.

What conversation happened between them?  How did they convince him to get married?

Answer (score 1):

Well it's a huge discussion, of which i am just giving a part. You can read it in [Srimad Devi Bhagavatam Mahā Puranam](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57117.html) in Book I Chapter 15-19.

**Srimad Devi Bhagwatam Mahā Puranam 1:18.:**

> *28-35. Janaka said :-- O Lord of Brāhmins! what you have said is, in my opinion, all quite true; nothing is false. Still hear. Know what my most worshipful Guru Deva has spoken to me is, in fact, true (and nothing else). You are now intending to quit the company of your father and go to the forest; well and good! but even then you will undoubtedly have the company of deer, etc.; see, also, that when the five elements, earth, water, air, etc., are present, encompassing everywhere, how, then, can you expect to be free from all companions? So, O Muni! when you will have to think always of your food, how, then, can you be said to be free from all cares? Again, even if you go to the forest, you will have to think there also for your staff, deer skin, etc.; so you can take my case, too, of thinking of my kingdom, whether I think or not, as your thinking of staff, deer skin, etc., your heart is tainted with Vikalpa Jñān (knowledge of doubt, duality, etc.); and therefore you have come here from a far-off country. But my heart is free from any such doubt and I am remaining quite cheerful here. O best of Brāhmins! I have got no doubt whatsoever on any point, and therefore I take my food and go to sleep with great pleasure. “I am not bound up by this world” this idea gives me constant happiness of the highest degree. But you consider that you are bound and therefore you feel always constant pain. So leave off your idea that you are bound, and be happy. “This body is mine” this knowledge leads to my bondage; and “This body is not mine” this knowledge leads to freedom so know this verily that all this wealth, kingdom, etc., are not mine.*
>
> *36-45. Sūta said :-- Hearing these words of the royal sage, Śūka Deva became exceedingly glad and pronounced “Sadhu” “Sādhu” (true saint, indeed a true saint, well said) and went away without any delay to the pleasant Āśrama of Vyāsa. Vyāsa, too, seeing his son come back, became very glad and embraced him and took the smell of his head and asked about his welfare again and again. Then Śūka Deva, well conversant with the Śāstras and ever ready in studying the Vedas, sat by the side of his father, with an enlightened mind, in his lovely Āśrama and thinking of the state of the highsouled Janaka in his kingdom, began to feel the highest peace. Though Śūka adopted the path of Yoga, yet he married the daughter of a Muni, named Pivarī, very beautiful, fortunate, enhancing the glory of her father’s family...."*

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..